# Malformed models - but I dont see how

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I keep getting these inner join errors when I try to delete an object.  It's a programming error, and an exception value of "column main_reviewerauthoranswer.screener_id does not exist
    LINE 1: ...viewerauthoranswer" INNER JOIN "main_reader" ON ( "main_revi..."

I'm using south. I'm migrating just fine. Creating instances just fine. But if I try to delete something I keep getting those errors. I don't know if something changed in django 1.6 with through tables? I'm very confused.

So this is what I"m doing. Empty database. I create a reader in the admin, I give the reader a genre ( I create it in the admin). Save. No problem. Ok, try to delete the reader I get 
column main_reviewerauthoranswer.screener_id does not exist
LINE 1: ...viewerauthoranswer" INNER JOIN "main_reader" ON ( "main_revi...

If i try to delete the genre I just created for that reader I get a 
column main_reviewerauthoranswer.screener_id does not exist
LINE 1: ...viewerauthoranswer" INNER JOIN "main_reader" ON ( "main_revi...

So obviously there is something wrong with my ReviewAuthorAnswer model. But I dont' see what

My models looks like this:

```
class DateDocumentation(models.Model):
    modified_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Author(DateDocumentation):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True)

class Reader(DateDocumentation):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)    
    favorite_genre = models.ForeignKey('Genre')


class Genre(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100

class Book(DateDocumentation):
    author = models.ForeignKey('Author')
    book = models.FileField(upload_to='books/')
    genre = models.ForeinKey('Gengre')

class Blurbreview(DateDocumentation):
    reader = models.ForeignKey("Reader")
    review = models.ForeignKey("Review")


class Review(DateDocumentation):
    book = models.ForeignKey('Book')
    blurb_readers = models.ManyToManyField("Reader",
                                       through="blurbreview",
                                       related_name='blurb_readers')
   readers = models.ManyToManyField("Reader",
                                 help_text="Readers that downloaded this book",)


class BaseQuestion(DateDocumentation):
    review = models.ForeignKey("Review")
    reviewer = models.ForeignKey("Reader")

class AuthorQuestion(DateDocumentation):
    review = models.ForeignKey('Review')

class ReviewerAuthorAnswer(DateDocumentation):
    question = models.ForeignKey('AuthorQuestion')
    screener = models.ForeignKey('Reader')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to rebuild the database. When you import new data, make sure that you run foreign_key_check=0; before the query.

I ran into this issue several times when I mistakenly tried importing data into an emptied database.

Comment: Welp dropping all the tables worked. I have no idea what caused the issue originally. But w/e. Just glad it didn't happen on a production server :D